# Error SDK facebook and Unity3d 5

Tags: facebook, unity

I've tried everything anyone has seen this error?

Clicking the invite: I get the message "App Request dialog is not implemented in the Unity editor."

```
public void InviteFriends()
     {
         FB.AppRequest(
             message: "T...",
             title: "...."
             );
     }
```

Clicking share: "Share Link is not implemented in the Unity editor"

```
public void ShareWithFriends()
     {
       //FB.Feed or
       FB.ShareLink (
             contentURL: "http://apps.facebook.com/" + FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag=" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ? FB.UserId : "guest"),
             contentTitle: "...",
             contentDescription: "....",
             photoURL: ";....",
             callback: LogCallback
             );
     }

     void LogCallback(FBResult response) {
         Debug.Log(response.Text);
     }
```

[image]

Comment: The guy can not answer
,negative and the question
lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for **Unity3d 5** And **facebook sdk 7.0.2**

first trade code

```
//GUI.ModalWindow(GetHashCode(), new Rect(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight), OnGUIDialog, "Unity Editor Facebook Login");
for
GUI.Window(GetHashCode(), new Rect(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight), OnGUIDialog, "Unity Editor Facebook Login");
```

in following path

> C:..\Assets\Facebook\Scripts\PlatformEditor\EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs

and "App Request" of 
"Share Link is not implemented in the Unity editor"

"App Request dialog is not implemented in the Unity editor."

just run the application simulating the cell